Advanced Scenarios in Clean Architecture
We have a very complex and mature ASP.NET web application that is about 20 years old and has 5 million lines of code spread across roughly 30 project in a single monolithic solution.
It's running on .NET Framework which is no longer being supported by Microsoft using WebForms.
We are in the early stages of rewriting it using .NET Core API (backend) with Angular (separate front end) using Clean Architecture.
However, all the examples I came across online (GitHub, PluralSight, YouTube, Clean Architecture Book, etc.) are simple demos. They usually consist of 4 Projects:

Presentation (API Controllers)
Infrastructure (HttpServices, Persistence, Logging, etc.)
Application (Use Cases, Services, Managers, Orchestrators, etc.)
Domain (Entities, Domain-Level Validation, etc.)

I don't know if there is an upper-bound size limit on DLL sizes, but I have concerns about having the majority of the 5 million lines of code roughly separated between Application and Infrastructure.
With that said, does anyone have any diagrams showing more complex implementations of Clean Architecture?
I'm also aware we can have many flavors of Infrastructure projects. One for persistence, one for OS services, one for Network level services, etc., but the bulk of our logic is business-related. Is there way to separate our business concerns into multiple Projects/Components? Any diagrams of this would be much appreciated.
Below, is something we came up with, to create at least some separation between regular services and master-level services based on Jeff Bezos' Api Mandate. This at least separates several million lines of code by 2 projects instead of all being inside of one.


"It's running on .NET Framework which is no longer being supported.." wait thats still suppo... "..using WebForms" oooohhh

If I were in your shoes, I would seek for an approach which allows to migrate to a different technology with rewriting as few lines of code as possible. Forget about the whole "Clean Architecture" hype - find something which is economically feasible, otherwise you will fail.  See also https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/ (and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6268).

@DocBrown thank you for your feedback, I appreciate it. We are not rewriting from scratch, but are migrating to a new platform as .NET Framework is no longer supported, but that's not the biggest issue. We are using an older tech stack which uses WebForms which is tightly coupled to the backend. And we are now finding it difficult to find developers which know WebForms and the whole Page Life Cycle. So in short, we will be attempting to migrate to a modern tech stack with Angular on the front end, while keeping majority of business layer in tact.

@Pavel: yes, you already wrote that. Your frontend technology is outdated, so you need to replace it. I would recommend to keep as much as you can from the existing backend, including its current structure, even if this might violate some CA ideas.

I don't have actual project diagram I can share, but the ideas are fairly straight-forward and will scale.
One way to understand Clean is to re-drawn it using the more conventional layers (see below).  Each of the black bounding boxes represents a layer.  I've also called out dependencies separately.  I have depicted the Entities and Use Cases as one layer - obviously you can separate them if you wish.
The "flow of control" diagram (in the Clean diagram) is basically saying that Layers can consume downwards e.g. technical components like the UI can consume application logic (not the other way around), and that application logic can consume externals like databases (not the other way around).  The critical caveat being that you should use loose-coupling mechanisms like DI / Inversion of Control as appropriate (i.e. the "Interfaces Adaptors Layer" in Clean).

Update: one important correction - the connectors show "consumption" (before I incorrectly had them labeled as "dependency").

E.g. your UI will typically 'consume' the domain layer / app logic, and might do so by calling it directly, which doesn't violate Clean's Dependency Rule; diagramically this is "down the layers".
Data access code is consumed by the app logic - in this diagram that's also "down the layers" but in the Clean context it's going in the reverse direction, so that consumption needs to be abstracted out so that the Dependency Rule isn't violated.

The other architectural style you can employ ideas from is Vertical Slice.  Regardless, you just need to follow the classic high-cohesion / low-coupling principles.
You can then think about the potential packaging, deployment and tiering:

components in different layers are candidates for separate packaging.
components in different slices are candidates for separate packaging.

These options are not mutually exclusive, you can combine them in different ways - some of which may be dictated by the technology being used to implement a part of the architecture.
In this second diagram I have coloured the layers to show which of the Clean concepts they map to (Entities / Use cases, Interfaces & Adaptors, etc).

Update: response to comment about Components
Sorry if I was not clear - I was referring to components in a logical sense where "component" simply meant cohesive pieces of code, not a DLL specifically.
Thinking about how you want to logically structure the components of your system ties in with how they can then be packaged and deployed; how they will be reused; how you structure your .Net Projects and how the team(s) actually work on them.
I recall a massive project I worked on in 2010 where I think the project team had ~230 to 250 .Net projects across three solutions, where many projects were in at least 2 of those solutions... the amount of time it took to just open the IDE was poor, let alone compile.  The team was not in a position to refactor the codebase at that stage.
Going back to your situation and Clean, taking Cleans "Enterprise Business Logic" as an example... Lets say you identify you have 20 areas/topics of functionality, which translates into 20 areas of logic - you can choose to have 20 namespaces (MyApp.MyLogic.Billing), put them in 1 project and have them compile into 1 DLL, or you could go the other way and have 20 projects and 20 DLLs.
Or (if it made sense) groupings of several logic areas into the same DLL.  Lets say the areas of logic were of different complexity and size (and were correspondingly more likely to change) then you could have the big/complex logic in a single project per area, and smaller trivial ones grouped together AS LONG AS they were reasonably cohesive.  E.g. simple finance logic separate from simple product management logic.
When designing the logic structure, project structure and eventual packaging for deployment and use, you'll need to consider a number of aspects (which you probably already are thinking of, but for the sake of a more complete answer), including:

How to ensure appropriate coupling and cohesion between different parts of the logic, and with the other parts of your system.
Size and complexity.
How likely they are to change.
The degree to which they are, or are likely, to be reused by other parts of the solution.
How many instances there will be at runtime, in how many different environments (is it one instance in a backend service, or more complicated than that?).
How easy it will be to modify the code.
How easy it will be to consume the code e.g. for UI and API developers to build their part of the solution on top of the logic.
How is the project team(s) likely to be structured; how many developers do you have, etc.

If all else is equal: the more likely it is that something will change (maybe because it is big, complex, is heavily reused, meets real world needs that are volatile, etc) then:

the more easy it needs to be to facilitate that change (e.g. easy to work on without impacting others, other parts of the code, test, etc)
and minimize the impacts of the change (e.g. ease of deployment, manage breaking changes, etc).

But that's getting into broader solution considerations such as which system qualities you need to prioritize, which is beyond the scope of this.
Code to Deployment
Based on your question, I spent some time yesterday thinking about how to portrait a Clean based architecture as logical components and then how that could translate into deployment - not what the actual packages were but just where the code needs to end up; from this sort of view you could start identifying actual deployment packages.
This first diagram (below) is basically the same as the first one at the top of my answer: an interpretation of Clean architecture as conventional horizontal layers, showing logical code and components:

This diagram (below) identifies which code is specific to an application and which is common / reused.

This diagram (below) shows where the code is eventually deployed into an application.  This is NOT showing specific DLL's and deployment packages, merely where the logical code ends up in terms of which application it is deployed to.


Thank you Adrian. I have a question when you say, "components in different layers are...". After reading the Clean Architecture book and applying it to .NET environment, it seems that a Component is equivalent to a DLL which in turn is equivalent to a Project. A .NET solution can have multiple Projects (DLLs). With that said, I'm finding that each "Layer" is a "Component/Project". We have 5 million lines of mostly Use Cases (business logic). Is it possible to break this out into multiple projects/components/DLLs?

hmmmm i think you might have gone wrong here with "application logic can consume externals like databases" and your diagram with domain "consuming" persistence

Consumption isn't meant to imply a dependency; think Ports & Adaptors.

yeah its not impossible to be CA and also follow your diagrams, but I think you have to question when all your dependencies are inverted with interfaces are you really following the spirit of the idea?

I can see how your combination of vertical splits and layer splits could lead to a million projects though.

it seems like you are combining the domain and application layer, which makes it look odd, whereas I would have the domain layer as fundamental data structs, which are passed through all layers and the application layer pulling in various services (via interfaces) in order to implement the functionality. but with the diagrams only having the downward flow of dependency it makes it look different to the in-then-out flow noramlly associated with CA

Agreed - I was taking a short-cut - I guess trying to simplify it slightly - which is maybe less than ideal, I was hoping the main ideas would be clear enough.  Do you think it's worth re-doing to show them explicitly?


However, all the examples I came across online (GitHub, PluralSight,
YouTube, Clean Architecture Book, etc.) are simple demos. They usually
consist of 4 Projects:

Yes this is super annoying, everyone seems to think that CA == one project per layer, but it obviously can't be true.

Here we have "Uncle Bob"s famous diagram, clearly you can't put your UI and DB in the same dll and have it make sense.
However, I haven't found a clear example. You have to dig into other Rob C Martin books to find that he thinks .net components are ddls and that small, many components are good and infer that the Devices, Web, Controllers etc are components to make the argument to people who think one project is all you need and don't understand interfaces.
My advice would be to go look at some of Microsoft own open source .net solutions. You will find millions of small projects per solution.

Exactly, I read his book several times to fully grasp this concept. He is indeed referring to DLLs or Projects when referring to components, when it comes to .NET environments. So with this in mind, all examples of Clean Architecture for .NET include just 4 project solutions.

the eShopOnContainers app is a great stop: https://github.com/dotnet/eShop

mmmmm its got Ordering.Infrastructure and Ordering.API with an infrastructure folder. You are just best not to use layer names for projects

@Pavel yeah I think he calls it out explicitly in "Clean Coding" I would have to check for the exact ref though.

@Pavel I think there is a hard problem to overcome with people who just like to put everything in one project. If you have experience with a solution that has more than one end use application in it, like a console app and a web app, or an admin app and a consumer app, or multiple distinct databases/external apis, then you understand the benefits of splitting things up into projects. But if you have always just had a single application per git repo, then its hard to grasp the idea that layers != components#

@Pavel - CA talks primarily about high level principles of how you control dependencies between components, and the logical layering. How (or if) you break down that application into DLLs (or distributed services, or whatever) is an orthogonal concern. So the main thing is not what projects to make; it's how to logically layer the code by responsibilities. Also note that "Entities" here doesn't mean database (EF) entities, it means the code that captures the high-level, core business rules. Suppose the use case is "if there's a spike in usage, notify someone" 1/2

The entities layer contains code that captures what is considered a spike, and only that. It's often not runnable/usable without the others; the outer components act as plugins or orchestrators. The use cases layer covers operational concerns by defining abstractions like "usage data source" and "subscribers" and by orchestrating how and when these are called, what is fed to the entities layer and when, and what is sent out. The interface adapters implement these abstractions, and decide where the data is actually taken from, in what format, where it's sent out and by what mechanism, etc. 2/2

@FilipMilovanović thanks for your input. I completely agree with most of what you said, and think there was one part in the book on CA where Uncle Bob specifically says that Components are DLLs in .NET. For other frameworks he explains that Components can be “other” things. Since my question is .NET specific, it’s really asking about advanced scenarios in large and complex projects, on how to draw dependencies and have more than 4 Components/Projects (DLLs).

@Pavel - my point was that the key concern is what to put in which DLL, which you'll know after you've worked how the system breaks down into logical layers and components; this then enables you to turn some of those logical boundaries into physical ones to end up with the DLLs. What DLLs you end up with (how you separate the system into components) will be specific (to greater or lesser degree) to the needs of your application, so a "canned" starter project that you might find out there will need tweaking (or might not be suitable at all). Note that DLLs can also cut across layers. 1/2

What I'm trying to suggest is to focus on domain modeling (rather than what specific DLLs to start with); this will give you some context to understand CA ideas. My earlier comments were an attempt at clarifying things by moving away from the more abstract language often used to describe CA. Approach the rewrite incrementally, and use your logical layering & domain model as a roadmap; carve out some code out of the legacy app; tidy it up, make it into a DLL, repeat. This book will probably be of help there. 2/2

"DLLs can also cut across layers" no

@Ewan - I think you're confusing components (in the CA sense) and DLLs. A component represents a smallest unit of deployment (a smallest a DLL can be), but otherwise you can organize components into a number of DLLs as is suitable for your deployment strategy. If DLLs weren't allowed to cut across (horizontal) layers, then you couldn't have, say, a DLL per feature (vertical slice) as an option (any preferences for other options aside), or indeed, an application that's a single executable (which, of course, is also an option in CA).

in terms of CA, components are in layers, so they can't cross them. the author of CA identifies components as DLLs in "clean coding". So i think you are incorrect in this sense. ie a vertical slice DLL with UI and DB code cant fit on the CA diagram. But also in the sense that such a DLL would have to pull in dependencies which would only be used for some parts of that DLL. ie you would reference entity framework in your client, even though you sent all db requests through an api

is a single exe application possible in CA? well you can always bundle all the dlls into an exe. but in terms of having a single statically linked application? I think that would go against the idea of components, which is critical to the overall idea of separating out the application logic into components and layers.

@Ewan - I'm not making any claims here that cannot be found in the Clean Architecture book by Martin. "I think [a single exe] would go against the idea of components" - this is a quote from the book: "Even when statically linked into a single executable, the ability to independently develop and marshal the various components for final assembly is immensely valuable." The point the book makes is to defer the decision on your deployment strategy (how to organize logical components into deployment components, like DLLs) until you have a better idea what fits the needs of the system.

"Such a DLL would have to pull in dependencies [only] used for some parts of that DLL" - sure, but this is not a problem at this level if you're not looking to deploy changes to that part independently. Development-wise, if you zoom in, the decoupling work has already been done internally at the source code level (there are layers and logical components inside). Also, "across layers" could be across a subset of layers - there are many ways to slice the cake. For ref: See CA book Chapter 33 "Case Study: Video Sales", Component Architecture section, and the subsequent chapter by a guest author.

tbh Think chap 33 backs me up fully. "I would certainly break the compile and build env up [dll per component]" The he goes into combining jar files in various ways. which you can do without recompiling, Chap 34 directly calls out the anti pattern of bundling components together "having all your infrastructure code in a single source code tree means its potentially possible for .. code in one area of your application ie web.. to directly call code in another... ie database" its virtually the same as my comment above

also chap 34 "ideally .. separate source code tree for each and every component.." and then hand waves reasons not to.

@Ewan - we're not in disagreement about componentization at the source code level. The point we were debating (the thing you challenged) is the "combining jar files in various ways" bit, i.e. deployment. Some of those ways (discussed in Ch 33) cut across layers. In Ch 34 the approach the guest author ends up recommending also cuts across (some of the) layers when it comes to packaging (just not to the same extent as the antipattern you're referring to). The point is that how you go about it is not mandated by CA, but a decision to be made - one enabled by CA practices in the first place.

@FilipMilovanović I think the difference is that the OP is asking about project structure in c# where a project compiles to a dll and you you distribute dlls in nuget packages. Here I argue that componentisation at compile/build means a project per component. chapt 34 says he disagrees with RM, but then goes on to say exactly why you should split by component (prevent cross references) and that it would be "ideal".  Plus this kind of static linking has the implicit assumption that you only have one application in your application layer, you can't reuse components without reusing everything.

The annoying thing though isnt people with well structured static single exes carefully obeying all the dependency rules without using language features to do so. Its people who make a project per layer and say "Right now im doing CA!" regardless of how the code is structured otherwise

Couldn't agree more on that last point. In fact, what motivated my original comment was that I felt the OP was overemphasizing the project structure as central to the problem they are facing; not an unimportant concern, but there's more to it than that.
